# Add more button if more 8 items

Tags: php, wp-query

I want to add a "more" button if more than 8 elements, I tried it

```
        <div class="under-menu__countries">
            <span class="under-menu__title">Countries</span>
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'cat' => $li->term_id,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                // var_dump(  $args);
                $countries = new WP_Query($args);
                if ( $countries->have_posts() ) : while ( $countries->have_posts() ) : $countries->the_post(); 
                $country_flag = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'country', true);
                $country_flag = explode(" ",$country_flag);
                $country_flag = implode("-",$country_flag);
                ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="um__counties--wrap">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/pictures/flags/24/<?php echo $country_flag; ?>.png"  alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"
                        title="<?php the_title(); ?> photo"
                        class=""/>
                        <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>                            
                </a>
                <?php 
                    if($countries > 7) {
                        echo "more";
                    }
                 ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Should it display all countries or only first 8 and then more button?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I have all the countries displayed, but I hid the styles, but I want the “more” button to be added after 8 and I could style it

Comment: <?php 
                         if($countries > 1) {
                          echo '<span class="under-menu__title">TEST</span>';
                         }
                         ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$countries` is not a number, but w `WP_Query` instance, so you can't compare it with a number...

This means that you should replace this:

```
if ($countries > 7) {
```

with:

```
if ( $countries->found_posts > 7 ) {
```

It will check if there are more than 8 countries that match your criteria. This way you can even change '-1' to '8' and limit the number of posts you're displaying and this condition will still work.

Comment: Thanks, checked out of the loop and everything works, but if -1 to put does not work. put 8 everything works